# Update PowerQuery function to return data from named table column and row, not just row in specific column

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have some `M` code that returns a value from a specified row on a named table in Excel (called *fParameters*):

```
let Parameter=(TableName,RowNumber) =>
    let
        Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=TableName]}[Content],
        value = Source{RowNumber-1}[Value]
    in
        value
in Parameter
```

I use the function to set where I want to load the raw data from:

```
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(fParameters("Parameters",1) & fParameters("Parameters",4)),null, true),
S1_Sheet = Source{[Item="S1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
```

The code above will look at rows 1 and 4 of the *Parameters* table to return the source file.  It will then get the data from the *S1* worksheet on that source file.

**The Problem:**
I would like to change the function so that I can change the name of the column it looks at.  At the moment it looks at the `[Value]` column.  I have tried adding `ColumnName` as the third parameter for the function, but can't get it to look at that column - at best it looks for a column called `ColumnName`.

```
let Parameter=(TableName,RowNumber,ColumnName) =>
    let
        Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=TableName]}[Content],
        value = Source{RowNumber-1}[ColumnName]
    in
        value
in Parameter
```

I've tried variations with the curly brackets, but can't get it to work.  Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(TableName,RowNumber,ColumnName) =>
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=TableName]}[Content],
value = Table.Column(Source,ColumnName){RowNumber-1}
in value
```

Comment: This is a tough one - two answers at the same time, both work and are very similar.  Going for this one as it returns the value, while the one from @Ricardo returns a table (I think - this one has the ABC icon next to it, Ricardos has a small 2-column table icon).  Thanks both for the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is just select the column and then refer to the row

```
let Parameter=(TableName,RowNumber,ColumnName) =>
    let
        Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=TableName]}[Content],
        SelectColumn = Table.SelectColumns(Source, ColumnName),
        SelectValue = SelectColumn{RowNumber-1}
    in
        SelectValue
in Parameter
```